# Is an ID allowed to be empty in an HTML tag?

Tags: html

Is the ID attribute on an HTML element allowed to be empty?

```
<div id=""></div>
```

I'm using a template where the ID of the element is set by a variable which may not always have a value and I'm wondering if this could cause any unforeseen problems.

EDIT: The "variable" is actually an editable region (block) in a Django template.  This means I can't put any conditional logic on it.

```
<div id="{% block id %}{% endblock %}">
```

Rather than:

```
<div {% block id %}{% endblock %}>
```

Which would have to be inherited in the sub-template as:

```
{% block id %}id="whatever"{% endblock %}
```

Comment: I'm using [ractive.js](http://www.ractivejs.org) and Have the same problem. You must use:

    <input id="{{value}}" />

instead of 

    <input {{#value}}id="{{value}}"{{/value}} />

which is a drawback for me, but I'm attached to the template rules.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

According to the W3C:

> ID and NAME tokens must begin with a
>   letter ([A-Za-z]) and may be followed
>   by any number of letters, digits
>   ([0-9]), hyphens ("-"), underscores
>   ("_"), colons (":"), and periods
>   (".").

(Source: [Basic HTML data types](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/types.html#type-id))

This would indicate that a blank value for the attribute is not valid in accordance with the above definition.

Trying to validate against an empty ID attribute returns the following:

> syntax of attribute value does not
>   conform to declared value
>
> `<div id="">something</div>`
>
> The value of an attribute contained
>   something that is not allowed by the
>   specified syntax for that type of
>   attribute. For instance, the
>   “selected” attribute must be either
>   minimized as “selected” or spelled out
>   in full as “selected="selected"”; the
>   variant “selected=""” is not allowed.

Comment: Trying to enter that on the W3C validator (http://validator.w3.org) returns an error.

Answer (score 4):

Even if no browser will crash on empty IDs, if you wanna generate valid HTML, you should generate fake IDs and differents, say, prefix + counter.

Comment: I guess I could always just set some default, overarching ID that gets used if none is provided.  Since this tag will only appear once per page, it will always be unique.

Comment: Your answer brought me to the right solution, but I had to mark @Jamie's answer because he gave a better answer about why ID's weren't valid.

Comment: Why generate fake IDs? Wouldn't it make more sense to omit the id-attribute?

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't set it to blank initially, just have the script (or however means your inserting your ID) append an attribute to the `div`. That way your code will validate, if that means anything to you.

Blank attributes are not valid, but having no attribute **is** valid. There shouldn't be any problems with it, just makes sure you are keeping your IDs unique. I'm sure you knew that, though.

Answer (score 1):

It wont validate as valid document.

W3 validator will give an error similar to : **syntax of attribute value does not conform to declared value**

Also id's should be unique. So if you have more than one with that it would violate that rule too.