# how to configure Rails tag to not generate HTML id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, html-helper

If you use a Rails helper like `check_box_tag` is it possible to tell it not to generate an HTML id or is the only option to override it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why would you want to do that, but I believe you can't do it. Look at the code for the **check_box_tag** helper:

```
def check_box_tag(name, value = "1", checked = false, options = {})
  html_options = { "type" => "checkbox", "name" => name, "id" => sanitize_to_id(name), "value" => value }.update(options.stringify_keys)
  html_options["checked"] = "checked" if checked
  tag :input, html_options
end
```

The closest you could do is pass **nil**, and that would generate `id=""`.

Comment: I just don't need an id for every checkbox in a table row. I use the name `model_ids[]`, such that checkboxes are grouped. The ids end up to be duplicates of each other. Btw an empty id is not valid. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6535934/is-an-id-allowed-to-be-empty-in-an-html-tag